# Como mezclar cadenas en C++?

Tags: c++, punteros, string

Tengo un parrafo y dos cadenas, debo de mezclar la cadena en unas posiciones del parrafo, como el ejemplo siguiente:

**Por ejemplo, si se ingresa el siguiente parrafo:**
"Ustedes y nosotros estamos
destinados a servir, no volvernos enemigos entre
la multitud..."

**la primer cadena:**
"no"

**la segunda cadena:**
"cad2"

**Se imprimira el parrafo siguiente:**
"Ustedes y nocad2sotros estamos
destinados a servir, nocad2 volvernocad2s enemigos entre
la multitud..."

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, deberias de poner un poco de codigo(lo que intentaste hasta ahora), o tu pregunta podria ser eliminada

Answer (score 0):

Lo que deseas es equivalente a reemplazar "no" por "nocad2".

Considerando lo anterior la logica es buscar todas las coincidencias de la primera palabra con el métodod `string::find()` y reemplazarlo con `string::replace()` como muestro a continuación:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void replaceAll(std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to) {
    if(from.empty())
        return;
    size_t start_pos = 0;
    while((start_pos = str.find(from, start_pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
        start_pos += to.length();
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string text1 = "no";
    std::string text2 = "cad2";
    std::string sentence = "Ustedes y nosotros estamos destinados a servir, no volvernos enemigos entre la multitud...";
    replaceAll(sentence, text1, text1 + text2);
    std::cout << sentence;
    return 0;
}
```

Salida:

```
Ustedes y nocad2sotros estamos destinados a servir, nocad2 volvernocad2s enemigos entre la multitud...
```